# Stripe customer: undefined method `payment_method`

Tags: ruby, stripe-payments

I’m working on the update of Stripe. We used the Stripe’s charge object but it’s not compatible with 3DSecure, so I migrate to the PaymentIntent API.

The problem is that, when I create a Stripe customer, I want to attach the payment_method as its mentioned in the documentation: https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/create#create_customer-payment_method

In my console, I’m able to do:

```
customer = Stripe::Customer.create(email: user.email)
customer.payment_method = 12345
customer.payment_method
=> 12345
```

First strange behaviour:

```
customer = Stripe::Customer.create(email: user.email)
customer.payment_method
=> NoMethodError (undefined method `payment_method' for #<Stripe::Customer:0x00007fd894fda560>)
```

`customer.payment_method` raises a NoMethodError instead of nil if there’s no value.

Anyway. In the console, I’m able to create a Stripe customer then attach a payment_method.

But when I try from a service with this code:

```
  def self.update_source(customer, payment_method_id)
    customer.payment_method = payment_method_id
    customer.save
  end
```

I get an error:

```
17:42:26 server.1 | (Status 400) (Request req_4aDqavkYeg5q3m) Received unknown parameter: payment_method_id excluded from capture: Not configured to send/capture in environment 'development'
17:42:26 server.1 |
17:42:26 server.1 | Stripe::InvalidRequestError (Received unknown parameter: payment_method_id):
```

I don’t know why the code works in the console but not from my service. I use the latest version of Stripe gem…

Any idea?

Comment: You should use this syntax to attach a PaymentMethod to a Customer : https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/attach?lang=ruby . PaymentMethods are different from sources, they are *not* embedded in the customer object(you list them using https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/list?lang=ruby for example, not looking at `customer.sources`; and there is no `payment_method` field on a Customer, hence the second error you got) so you should generally use the attach endpoint explicitly.

Comment: Thank you @karllekko, I’m now able to attach a customer to a PaymentMethod. Have a good day